# Wrong timestamp in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am getting the wrong timestamp format/timezone in return from MySQL. In MySQL the time is accurate and correct but when I select it from MySQL I get it like this

```
2020-03-22T19:00:04.000000Z
```

However, I have this in my database table

```
2020-03-22 07:00:02
```

The query which I am using to fetch results from db is:

```
Stats::select('created_at','total_cases','recovered','critical','deaths','islamabad'
,'punjab','sindh','kp','balochistan','ajk','gb')->whereDate('created_at', $date)->get();
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql) is of any help.

Comment: Is the db time 24-hour format?

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `date_format()` to print the date returned from the database according to the format you want. Here is an example:

```
$date=date_create("2020-03-22T19:00:04.000000Z");
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
#output 2020/03/22 19:00:04
```

Comment: You do realize OP is talking about the times not matching and not the format?

Comment: Actually the time matches: apply `date_format()` on the first time given and you will see that is the same time given in the second part of the question

Comment: I am using laravel, and the time I am fetching from database is for public api so I need to fetch it like it is in the DB

Comment: So what is that you want exactly: are you passing the date as a param and you don't know how to format it so it returns a result from the database or you want to display it as your first date shown in your question?

Comment: The PHP time says 19:00:04, while db time says 07:00:02. I don't see how that's a match fixable by formatting. The timezone needs to be amended.

Answer (score 1):

You can format your date using `DATE_FORMAT` function of mysql as below:

```
$data  =  Stats::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as formatted_dob'), 'total_cases','recovered','critical','deaths','islamabad'
    ,'punjab','sindh','kp','balochistan','ajk','gb')
    ->whereDate('created_at', $date)
    ->get();
```

Reference:

[MySQL -> date and time function -> date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: This also won't take care of the timezone mismatch, but I salute the formatting done directly in MySQL.